# How do I show labels on all (even pinned) items in the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, desktop-customization

I have set "Combine Taskbar Buttons" to "Never", but as you can see only the currently opened applications have a label next to them. How can I add labels to pinned items as well?

See image:

[image]

Comment: I'm willing to accept if there's a way to align all the icons to the extreme left. :\